# iOS - Interface design, images or custom drawing?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I've been looking at a lot of iOS user interfaces that have been customized. I wonder, is it better to customize the UI using images or using libraries like CoreGraphics and Quartz, or is it on a per case basis, as in I use libs for some elements and images for others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very hard to guess your particular situation. I can state that iOS gives us a lot of leverages to make any **custom interface**. I would use:

- **images** for complicated graphic elements, buttons, icons, arrows, etc.
- **images + stretching** to get complicated backgrounds/elements
- **custom drawing** all that contain lines, ellipses, squares, lineral and/or circular gradients, simple image preprocessing, etc.

The **key idea** is - to find **balance** between memory usage and processing time. Note: from my experience - interfaces based on images which created by **professional designer** looks **awesome**.

Answer (score 2):

Case-by-case basis. Images can be drawn more quickly but use more memory; custom drawing, whether via Core Graphics or Quartz, uses less memory but takes more time.

Answer (score 1):

Case by case. If you want a lot of complex graphics that aren't lines and don't change much, use images. If you just need lines/gradients, or if you want things to move and morph, you'll need to use quartz.

It depends on you, as well. Would you rather write code for quartz for an hour and debug it, or would you rather spend an hour in photoshop? How fast are you at PS? Do you already know Quartz?

Comment: I'm dumb as a doorknob on both

Answer (score 1):

It depends on a lot of things, so "case-by-case".

Determine the complexity of each approach. (nontrivial) Icons are a good example of an image, while large gradients are a good use for drawing. Drawing can take some time/experience to get right, compared to graphic assets, but you can reuse that implementation later and use less memory in many cases (images can also use less memory - depending on what you're drawing). Complex static images can take time to render if drawn so... there are a number of things to consider in order to achieve the best balance. Using the gradient vs. image example, quality and time are also factors -- resizing/scaling a simple image can take a lot of CPU or have artifacts a rendered gradient would not have. Much of it comes down to experience, knowing the implementations you use well, and a lot of sampling/profiling to determine what is simple/complex/consumes a lot of memory, and so on.

Comment: So let's say, I'd use images for the NavBar, the Tab Bar, the buttons, and for the table views I'd use gradients and drawing?

Comment: case by case. it depends on a lot of things. sometimes you just want what is easiest/fastest to implement, or one may look better than the other. other times, a number of factors will influence your decision.